# Enterprise Architect - default settings

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'm unable to find a way to reset Enterprise Architect (15.2) fully into its default settings. Is there one? I tried googling and exploring the menus without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, the only way to reset to default settings is to uninstall, and reinstall EA. And even then you might need to do some cleaning in the appdata and the registry to be sure.

EA stores some of the settings in the registry, and some of the settings in the appdata folder in your profile.

The registry settings can be found here:

- **Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Sparx Systems\EA400\EA**

The appdata settings here:

- **%appdata%\Sparx Systems\EA**

Comment: Not to forget: the MDGs shown are from the according folder in program data.

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to restore to original view, on Sparx 15.2, [Choose Start/Workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DWXc.png)

Choose Start, Workspace and change or select appropriate workspace, including default. This will change your view and windows.